# git conflicts - is there an easy way to get differences between the sections of a conflict?

Tags: git, conflict, git-diff, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

Given a conflict (or many) in a file, is it possible to *easily* get differences between the sections of a conflict? I mean, I know I can diff whole files from revisions and stuff but I also know it's **not** possible with git out-of-the-box to pinpoint specific sections of files for diffing. Is there some other already-cooked-in artiluge available in git to pinpoint a conflicted section of a file and get the differences between the two tips (or with the *ancestor*, if using `diff3`)?